# My ID field is getting a value when it shouldn't be

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my `[HttpGet] Create Action` I have this:

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
{ 
    ViewBag.TestTypeID = new SelectList(db.codeTypes, "ID", "TestType");

    OHealth oHealth = new OHealth();
    oHealth.OID = Convert.ToInt32(id);

    oHealth.DateEntered = DateTime.Today;

    return View(oHealth);
}
```

Now, `OID` is a foreign key, not the primary key `ID`.  As you can see I don't assign `ID` any value.. only `OID`.  `ID` is auto-incremented in the database.

Here is how my HTML renders for my Create View for `OID` and `ID`:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="2" />    
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field OID must be a number." data-val-required="The OID field is required." id="OID" name="OID" type="hidden" value="2" />
```

So when I hit create, the `ID` field is given the value of `2` when it should be `1` since it will be the first record in the database.

How is my `ID` field receiving a value of `2` when that hasn't been assigned?

Let me know if more is needed.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Razor for those 2 fields:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)    
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OID)
```

Comment: @freedomn-m see updated.

Comment: It's because of this `public ActionResult Create(int? id)`.  Gimme a sec to provide an explanation

Comment: @freedomn-m In my `OHealth` class, I have an empty constructor.

Comment: In the meantime, try changing to something else, eg `public ActionResult Create(int? anotherid)` (and change the url from `/Create/2` to `/Create?anotherid=2`)

Comment: If you step through at what point does the ID field get assigned a value?

Comment: And are you ever saving the oHealth field? You aren't showing it but since you talk about the ID field being auto-increment in the DB I assume you believe this to be relevant to your situation in some way...

Comment: @Chris that's the thing.. when i step through `HttpGet Create Action`.. the `ID` field isn't assigned.. it gets assigned a `2` at the binding of the `HttpPost Create Action`

Comment: Is it a post or a get?  Looks like a post, but your question says get and your comment says post

Comment: So at the end of the Create action `oHealth` has no ID? What about at the beginning of your view (ie put a break point on the first line)?

Comment: @freedomn-m in my `get` action (posted above) the `ID` field isn't assigned anything when i step through.. but when I step through the `Post` it is assigned a `2` before I even get into the Action method (i.e `public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,OID,Foo,Bar")] OfficerHealth officerHealth)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC automatically binds parameters into the modelstate.  So your parameter `id` in:

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
```

will be automatically put into `Model.ID` (as url params are case-insensitive).

You should be able to confirm this by changing the name of the parameter (and corresponding url/action definition), eg:

```
public ActionResult Create(int? anotherid)
```

and change the url from `/Create/2` to `/Create?anotherid=2`

This occurs automatically so that any values in a POST will automatically have the same values they had when the form was posted without you needing to explicitly set them.   In a GET this occurs from the parameters.

The fix is to add `ModelState.Clear()`:

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id) 
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return;

    ModelState.Clear();
```

this will stop the auto-rebinding when the view fields are regenerated.

The re-binding occurs after the view has been generated, all the field values are re-inserted from *ModelState*.  By clearing modelstate, you stop this from happening.

Comment: That worked! Thank you for the explanation! Much appreciated.